# angularjs - Request header field is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: jquery, asp.net, angularjs, cors, preflight

I'm using the lib https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap/ to connect an ionic app to an asmx webservice. However, I'm getting an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://10.10.9.169/UserService3/WebService1.asmxgetUserbyUsername.
>   Request header field SOAPAction is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. jquery.soap.js:456
>   Uncaught Error: Unexpected Content: undefined

Here's my `controller.js` code:

```javascript
$scope.enterlogin = function(usern,pass)
{
    $.soap({
        url: 'http://<webservice's ip address>/UserService3/WebService1.asmx',
        method: 'getUserbyUsername',

        data: {
            uname: usern,
            passw: pass
        },

        success: function (soapResponse) {
            console.log('response is = ' + soapResponse);
        },

        error: function (soapResponse) {
            // show error
            console.log('response error is = ' + soapResponse);
        }
     });
}
```

I've also added the following in the webservice's `web.config` file:

```xml
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.UI.WebServiceHandlerFactory" />
</httpHandlers>

<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Authorization" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message seems to indicate the request includes a header with the name `SOAPAction`.

So it seems like you need to add that header name to the following part of your `web.config` file:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers"
     value="SOAPAction, Content-Type, Authorization" />
```